# R ggplot2 legend combined with a color dictionary

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to automatize a ggplot2 code for an application where I often have different factors to plot. So I created a color dictionary specifying a color for each factor that could appear in my data:

```
colordict<-c(
"Nitrogen"="chartreuse4",
"genotype"="palegreen",
"normal"="purple2",
"loc"="cornflowerblue",
"stress"="orchid")
```

Now let's say I produce a sample bar plot from data with this code:

```
# library
library(ggplot2)

# create a dataset
specie <- c(rep("sorgho" , 3) , rep("poacee" , 3) , rep("banana" , 3) , rep("triticum" , 3) )
condition <- rep(c("normal" , "stress" , "Nitrogen") , 4)
value <- abs(rnorm(12 , 0 , 15))
data <- data.frame(specie,condition,value)

# Stacked + percent
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")+
scale_fill_manual(values=colordict)
```

[image: Resulting Plot]

As you can see, everything is correctly plotted (with 3 colors for the 3 condition factors in the plot), but on the legend, there appear unfortunately too many factors - in fact all that are specified in the color dictionary. But to keep the dictionary general, I need to specify there more colors than actually factors in some datasets. Therefore, I need a solution how to display only the relevant factors on the legend. It worked with the R version 3.9, but not with 4.1.

Comment: This is related to [this ggplot2 issue](https://github.com/tidyverse/ggplot2/issues/4511) and the proposed workaround is to set `limits = force`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(fill=condition, y=value, x=specie)) + 
  geom_bar(position="fill", stat="identity")+
  scale_fill_manual(values=colordict[unique(data$condition)])
```

output looks like this :

[image]

Is it what you wanted?